# Simple select from a table with multiple joins takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL database that is around ~**84mb**. The following query:

```
SELECT     
    `reservations`.`id`
FROM       
    `reservations` 
INNER JOIN `reservation_room` 
ON         `reservation_room`.`reservation_id` = `reservations`.`id` 

LEFT JOIN  `users` 
ON         `reservations`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 

INNER JOIN `rooms` 
ON         `reservation_room`.`room_id` = `rooms`.`id` 

INNER JOIN `stories` 
ON         `rooms`.`story_id` = `stories`.`id`

INNER JOIN `hotels` 
ON         `stories`.`hotel_id` = `hotels`.`id`

INNER JOIN `neighbourhoods` 
ON         `hotels`.`neighbourhood_id` = `neighbourhoods`.`id` 

INNER JOIN `cities` 
ON         `cities`.`id` = `neighbourhoods`.`city_id` 

GROUP BY   `reservations`.`id` 
ORDER BY   `reservations`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT      30 
OFFSET     0
```

And it takes around 4 to 700 seconds to execute. The `reservations` table has 48k records and `reservation_room` has 191k records. This query is executed quite often and it makes the mysql process go hard on the CPU:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 5021 mysql    20   0  755m 385m 8596 S 748.7  1.2   5353:58 mysqld
```

What can I do to speed up the query or at least not make the whole mysql server go crazy?

`EXPLAIN` of the query above:

[image]

98% of the time of execution is `Copying to temp table`.

Comment: are the columns that you are querying on indexed ?

Comment: @molecule Yes, all columns I'm using in my `JOIN`s are indexed.

Comment: are you only selecting reservations`.`id` ?

Comment: @isaace I have other columns in my select. I just wanted to make it simple. I don't use any functions in my select statements.

Comment: is there any use for group by without functions?

Comment: @isaace I'm using it because joining `reservation_room` to `reservations` and then `rooms` make `reservations` to have duplicates.

Comment: Since joins are not working efficiently because of the large number of rows in indexed columns. I suggest you break down your query into multiple IO's and write two different queries.

Comment: @molecule Can you please explain what "break down your query into multiple IO" means? Thank you!

Comment: you might want to try using distinct instead of group by.

Comment: You can just get the data till `stories` in your first query. After that make another query where you pass call the `story_id` and `neighbourhoods .id` to your query and make the second set of joins.

Comment: Why floors table does not appear on your query? There's a whole page dedicated to [block nested loops](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html) on mysql docs.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I'm still trying to name the tables. Floors is stories. I'm going to fix it now.